# Run subshell until all others have completed in bash

Tags: bash

So say I have something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
testfunc(){
    echo "blah"
    sleep 30
}

for blah in blahs; do
    testfunc &
done

wait
```

The script I have is calling a bunch of my functions in the bg, and waiting for them all to finish with no problem... But what I need to do is have another function that starts at the beginning of my script, and runs until after my wait, and then finishes.

```
#!/bin/bash
testfunc(){
    echo "blah"
    sleep 30
}

gatherloadavg(){
while true; do
    echo "my load averages and other performance data I want" >> blah.txt
done
}

gatherloadavg &
for blah in blahs; do
    testfunc &
done

wait
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wait` takes an optional list of PIDs to wait on.  So you should be able to do something like this:

```
gatherloadavg &
statspid=$!

for blah in blahs; do
    testfunc &
    pidlist="$pidlist $!"
done

wait $pidlist

kill $statspid
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know wait could take a list. This was exactly what I needed.